# cronjob googleAppEngine run script?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I've setup a GAE cronjob. My cron.yaml looks like this

```
cron:
- description: checkForPush
  url: /cron/
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

Inside the cron folder i've got a cron.py file with an URL-Fetch.
If i deploy the project and the cronjob runs it fails.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: in the cronjob tab is say:
http://picfront.org/d/V7cc2efoY8/cron.png

Comment: no one? would be very thankfull for any help!
In my logs 404 occurs.

In my app.yaml i've declared an url:
- url: /cron
  script: cron.py

...without success!

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell you what to fix if we don't know what's failing.

Do cron failures generate logs?  Check the "Logs" section of the admin console and see if there's anything in there.

Comment: I've changed the rediction to the main.py /* was redicted to main.py. now after changing that to / it works. chmod too. thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app.yaml declaration is for the url '/cron', but your cron.yaml is requesting '/cron/'. You need to change them so they both use the same path.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you go to /cron/ with a browser?  Do you also get a 404? If so, then your problem probably isn't with your cron setup but with your script.